# Display multiple data fields in BoundField of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `asp:GridView` which is bound. Within this I have multiple columns, I'm trying to get the data from two database fields concatenated into one field.

How to do this?

Something like this?

```
asp:BoundField DataField="field1 + ' ' + field2" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="info"
```

Comment: Proper capitalization and spelling is always a plus =)

Answer (score 26):

Pretty sure you need to use a TemplateField instead of BoundField for this.

In your GridView Columns Block:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 17):

Just for completeness, cause I searched a solution and came first here...

You have more flexibility by using `string.Format()`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
 <ItemTemplate>
     <%# string.Format("{0} {1}", Eval("field1") ,Eval("field2"))%>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here you can also use the power of `string.Format()` to format date and number types as descriped here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types

Sample:

```
<%# String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy} - {1:N2}", Eval("dateValue1"), Eval("decimalValue2")) %>
```

---

Another option is to do it in a custom method with code behind

ASPX:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#GetStatus(Eval("Status1"),Eval("Status2")) %>'>
      </asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Codebehind:

```
public string GetStatus(object Status1, object Status2)
{
    return (string)Status1 + " " + (string)Status2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ToolTip='<%# Eval("LastName") & "-" & Eval("FirstName") %>'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this.
If u are using two datasets make to one datatable and bind it to gridview.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "f1")%>+ ' ' + <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "f2")%>" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="info"/>
```

Comment: Don't you need to use template files for that? Not bound fields?

Comment: @pseudocoder: it does work, Container.DataItem is the current item, f1, f2 are the proprierties to be read from the current item.