# Concatenate values of columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

The `Page_Load()` code to retrieve records and display table.

```
        sConn = new SqlConnection(sStr);
        daEmp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblEmployee", sConn);
        daDep = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblDepartment", sConn);
        dsEmp = new DataSet();
        dsDep = new DataSet();

        daEmp.Fill(dsEmp, "tblEmployee");
        daDep.Fill(dsDep, "tblDepartment");

        dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Columns["EmployeeID"] };

        dgvEmployee.DataSource = dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"];
        dgvEmployee.DataBind();
```

The code for the table **dgvEmployee**:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="dgvEmployee" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" cssClass="mytable">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField datafield="EmployeeID" headertext="Employee ID"/>
    <asp:BoundField datafield="DeptID" headertext="Deprtment" />
    <asp:BoundField datafield="Lname" headertext="Last Name"/>
    <asp:Boundfield datafield="Fname" headertext="First Name"/>
    <asp:Boundfield datafield="Mname" headertext="Middle Initial"/>
    <asp:Boundfield datafield="Address" headertext="Address"/>
    <asp:Boundfield datafield="Email" headertext="Email"/>
    <asp:Boundfield datafield="Phone" headertext="Phone"/>
    <asp:Boundfield datafield="Jobtitle" headertext="Job Title"/>
    <asp:Boundfield datafield="Salary" headertext="Salary"/>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

How do I combine the three columns in this format: `Lname, Fname Mname`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097283/display-mulitple-data-fields-in-boundfield-of-gridview

Answer (score 2):

Please Try IT, I hope it's useful to you

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("FirstName") + ' ' + Eval("Middle")+ ' ' + Eval("LastName")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Might be easier to break down your evals for simplicity: <%# Eval("Contact.ContactFName")%> <%# Eval("Contact.ContactLName")%>

Answer (score 0):

oh i got it..

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fullname">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Fullname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Lname")+ ", " + Eval("Fname") + " " + Eval("Mname") + "." %>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: The eval's look questionable, but maybe they're OK in asp?