# Multiple datafields in boundfield using codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, boundfield

I am pulling a first name and last name from a SQL table, running it through a datatable and binding the datable to a gridview. Instead of having two different columns in my gridview, I would like to put the first and last name in the same column. The datable has the "FirstName" and "LastName" variables. I can do that in the aspx file using the eval function, however I would like to handle it in the Codebehind file.

I turned off AutoGenerateColumns, I created a BoundField. I can add FirstName to the bfield.Datafield and it will spit out the first name. Or Vice versa. How can I add BOTH FirstName and LastName to the same Boundfield in the codebehind?

```
 BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
 bfield.HeaderText = "Name";
 bfield.DataField = "FirstName" + " " + "LastName";
 gridview_viewPSC.Columns.Add(bfield);
```

That throws an error.

I know the data is coming through correctly. I can plug either in, and it will display the data.

Comment: how about starting off by telling us what the error is.. we are definitely not mind readers here.. also look at this link for more efficient way of doing the same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097283/display-mulitple-data-fields-in-boundfield-of-gridview

Comment: System.Web.HttpException: A field or property with the name 'FirstNameLastName' was not found on the selected data source

Comment: I did look at that link before, but I wanted to do this in the CodeBehind. Not the aspx page....

Comment: where are you assigning the gridview_viewPSC DataSource

Comment: You need to add a field "FullName" to the Datasource and put your logic for concattenation when you get the data.

Comment: In a different method... I can plug either the FirstName in and it will work. FirstName and LastName are two different columns in my datasource. I want to put both in the same column.

Comment: do you know Sql...? why not bind the gridview to a datatable or dataset..? please show all relevant code.. it makes it easier for others to understand your code vs looking at 4 lines of code that we have no idea what method or event that it's tied to..

Comment: I just want to know how to concatenate two pieces of data in the same field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI the answer is after your **DataTable** is loaded with your data, create a new ***DataColumn***. In my example the dt is loaded with Columns "FirstName" and "LastName".

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

DataColumn dcFullName = new DataColumn("FullName");
dcFullName.Expression = string.Format("{0}+' '+{1}", "FirstName", "LastName");
dt.Columns.Add(dcFullName);

gridview_viewPSC.DataSource =  dt;
```

**Then in your BoundField**

```
BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
bfield.HeaderText = "Name";
bfield.DataField = "FullName";
gridview_viewPSC.Columns.Add(bfield);
```